# How to setup wildcard ssl in centos

Tags: linux, centos, digital-ocean

What will be the proper way of setting wildcard ssl on domain using digitalocean.

The server run on centos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: I have to create txt in digital ocean after going through the output again

```
Please deploy a DNS TXT record under the name
_acme-challenge.domain.com with the following value:

WIThsMyXNxvWg0Udx_qjTKWbXJrIRIWDc_MSWhyQI4w
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is not with the wildcard. *.domain.com should work just fine for all the subdomains but not for the domain.com itself.
Here the problem is that the domain verification failed, so the DNS record was not set perfectly. Could you show, how you set it?

Comment: The dns is set in digitalocean

Comment: Well, I can't help with that, but the problem is there.